# long subsection title doesn't fit in header beamer

Tags: beamer

I have a very long subsection title and I would like to know how it is possible to change the size or go back to the line.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be avoided by specifying a shorter version of the subsection title that will be used in the headline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\subsection[short subsection name]{long subsection name}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```